# Installing things from git

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am running an ubuntu server and would like to install https://github.com/xat/castnow
on it, the documentation has nothing for ubuntu, how does this work?

Comment: You're asking us to tutor you on installing something from Github? That's not what we do here. Ask the project team for instructions.

Comment: I'm asking for understanding of what is being said by the install instructions. Documentation for how to install random github software is few and far between, so I am asking here to understand.

Comment: SO is not the tutorial site for installing *random github software*. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, etc.). When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages. Please do so, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); if you can find *installation instructions for random github projects* on that list, let me know. [ask] says that all relevant info must be here, not in a link to a *random github project*, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The readme on the github page has this:

### Install

```
sudo npm install castnow -g
```

---

You will also need nodejs and npm, if you don't already have those.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: Flag off topic questions instead of answering them.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the repo is for Node.js, I don't think you'll be able to do anything more than clone this to your local machine with git.

You can still install this on Ubuntu however, you'll just have to install Node.js first then run the install command listed in the documentation.

`sudo npm install castnow -g`

[Here's a guide on how to install Node.js and npm on Ubuntu.](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-npm-on-ubuntu-16-04/)